# .Net 5. Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'IServiceProvider'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Задеплоил приложение на heroku, после деплоя все работает. Если приложение не используется N время, то падает пул и сервер засыпает. При рестарте пула не работают сервисы, которые зарегистрированы через AddSingleton().

Я решил поменять регистрацию на AddTransied(), но теперь возникает ошибка при инициализации IServiceProvider(Cannot access a disposed object) в хендлере Mideatora, т.е. вызов хендлера не происходит и возникает исключение. Что я делаю не так?

Регистрирую так:

```
services.AddTransient<IBotService, BotService>()
services.AddTransient<IMessageHandlerService, MessageHandlerService>()
services.AddMediatR(typeof(GetClientByTelegramChatIdHandler).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
```

Вызываю сервисы через сервис BotService, на который тоже перерегистрировал через AddTransied. Через сервис обрабатываются события:

```
public class BotService : IBotService {
    public async Task Watch() {
        if (_botClient.IsReceiving) {
            return;
        }

        await _botClient.SetWebhookAsync("");
            _botClient.OnMessage += BotOnMessage;
            _botClient.OnCallbackQuery += BotOnCallback;
            _botClient.StartReceiving();
        }

    private async void BotOnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs eventMessage) {
        try {
            await _messageHandlerService.HandleText(eventMessage.Message);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            _logger.LogError($"Error on client {eventMessage.Message.Chat.Id}. {e.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

Вызов медиатора:

```
public class MessageHandlerService : IMessageHandlerService {
        public async Task HandleText(Telegram.Bot.Types.Message message) {
            if (message == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message.Text)) {
                return;
            }

            var client = await _mediator.Send(new GetClientByTelegramChatId(message.Chat.Id));
}
```

Хендлер:

```
public class GetClientByTelegramChatIdHandler : IRequestHandler<GetClientByTelegramChatId, TelegramClientDto> {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public GetClientByTelegramChatIdHandler(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IMapper mapper) {
            Contract.Requires(mapper != null);

            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        public async Task<TelegramClientDto> Handle(GetClientByTelegramChatId request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
            using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();

            var repository = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDbRepository<TelegramClient>>();
            var clients = await repository.GetAsync();
            var client = clients.ToList().FirstOrDefault(c => c.ChatId == request.ChatId);
            
            return _mapper.Map<TelegramClientDto>(client);
        }
```

Comment: Обработчик вызывается асинхронно, и к этому моменту ServiceProvider уже разобран. Вставьте зависимость на IDbRepository<TelegramClient> напрямую, а не резолвите ее на лету